# MYSQL - How to store List of certain number of data? Also storage limited to that number

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to store data of members (between 0 to 5000) for a file till a certain number.

As of now, I'm storing 9 members, for that, I've created individual columns. By doing this I am able to join different tables.

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE file (
    file_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    file_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    file_admin INT NOT NULL,
    member1 INT,
    member2 INT,
    member3 INT,
    member4 INT,
    member5 INT,
    member6 INT,
    member7 INT,
    member8 INT,
    member9 INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (file_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (file_admin) REFERENCES users(user_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (member1) REFERENCES users(user_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (member2) REFERENCES users(user_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (member3) REFERENCES users(user_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (member4) REFERENCES users(user_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (member5) REFERENCES users(user_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (member6) REFERENCES users(user_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (member7) REFERENCES users(user_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (member8) REFERENCES users(user_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (member9) REFERENCES users(user_id)
);
```

You can clearly see there are number of values are NULL here. What if a file has 5000 members, then creating that number of columns can be difficult and also many values will be NULL.

How can I store these data till certain number(In this case 5000) in MYSQl. Also storage limited to that number, also I should be able to join table based on the FOREIGN KEY of these data.

Comment: Pro tip: If you are designing a database and you find yourself thinking "I'll have to add columns to this table when I get more users", stop! When you have variable numbers of things in your application, you almost always put them in rows, not columns.

Comment: @O.Jones Thanks, your tip will definitely help me in my future database design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answers the original version of the question.

The right way to store this is with a different *table*:

```
CREATE TABLE files (
    file_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    file_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    file_admin INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE file_members (
    file_member_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    file_id INT NOT NULL
    member_id INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (file_id) REFERENCES files(file_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (member_id) REFERENCES users(user_id),
    UNIQUE (file_id, member_id)
);
```

Note that `NOT NULL` is redundant on a primary key, and the primary key declaration can be in-lined.

Comment: Due to duplication of the question, I added more specific details to my question. Can you check this?

Comment: @kallis . . . The correct thing to do is to ask a *new* question.  Modifying a question and invalidating answers is impolite.